# The jean button was dropdowned, I have to go to tailor shop to replace the jean button

Tags: vocabulary

In the sentence:

> The jean button was dropdowned, I have to go to tailor shop to replace the jean button.

Do we use *replace* or *fix* that jean button?

Comment: _The jean(s) button came off/got lost, and I have to go to the tailor to replace it._ *_Dropdowned_ is clever, but not English.

Comment: Your questions are probably a better fit for http://ell.stackexchange.com/ (English Language Learners)

Comment: I suspect that when you say "the jean button was dropdowned", you really mean  "the jean button _fell off_".

Comment: @ErikKowal Perhaps it’s one of those special graphical user interface buttons that when activated reveals a dropdown menu craftily printed on the underwear behind the trousers. The hard part is finding the `C̲o̲n̲t̲r̲o̲l̲` key to allow for multiple selections. 

Comment: @tchrist - That's a very intriguing suggestion... Do you think we could monetize it?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With regard to "replace" vs "fix"

You would **replace** the button if the button was lost.  You would not **fix** the button, you would **repair** the jeans.

Comment: Fix can also be used to mean _fix in place_

Comment: @Frank If that were the meaning he was discussing, _replace_ would not be a possible alternative.